# Is there any way to compare two excel formulas?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have found some tools that compares two excel files, but the problem is that they check only the cell result and not it's formula. For example:

`A1 = PRODUCT(B1,C1)` which gives me a result of 0.
`B1 = PRODUCT(B1,C1,D1)` which also gives me a result of 0.

The problem is that all tools I have used, they give me A1=B1 true as a result, whereas they don't have the same formula. Is there any solution to this problem?

I don't have excel pro edition so I haven't used Excel's compare files functionality.

Comment: VBA is probably the only solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel 2013 you can use [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) nested in an `IF` statement to check if the text of the formulas are the same.

```
=IF(FORMULATEXT(A1)=FORMULATEXT(B1), "True", "False")
```

In this case, using the formulas you indicated in cells `A1` & `B1`, the cell the above formula is in would return `False`. If they match, it would return `TRUE`.